# App get blank Screen on ipod

Tags: ios, crash, ipod

When I run my app on iPod 4G, it only shows a blank screen. Here is the log:

```
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 11779]
[Switching to thread 11779]
Re-enabling shared library breakpoint 1
continue
objc[1014]: Class OutgoingMessage is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message and /var/mobile/Applications/2930A145-7E61-4083-B893-FDBAE148FEF7/ABC.app/ABC. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1014]: Class Message is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME and /var/mobile/Applications/2930A145-7E61-4083-B893-FDBAE148FEF7/ABC.app/ABC. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Watchdog has expired.  Remote device was disconnected?  Debugging session terminated.
Watchdog has expired.  Remote device was disconnected?  Debugging session terminated.

The Debugger has exited due to signal 15 (SIGTERM).The Debugger has exited due to signal 15 (SIGTERM).
```

Can anyone help me to solve this? This is working on iPhone 4, iPhone 3gs, and iPad1.

Comment: I had this once happen to me when I disconnected the device midway between a debug. And I got this error message till I rebooted the device. Have you tried that already?

Comment: yup i had try it . but still that msg and blank screen appear ..! Frustrated on this bug .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running a sample code to see if this is a problem with your code or your device. If the problem is your code, try incrementally commenting out stuff from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Also watch out for classes (like `MFMailComposeViewController`) where you have to check for its capabilities (like `canSendMail`) before using them

Comment: My code is working on iphone and ipad it only shows blank screen on ipod .. !! and i have check both this file nothing i found ..